# what is mean by the following statement in java (MY_CLASSPATH=lib/*:properties:.)

Tags: java

I want to understand the following statement, could you please share your knowledge on this.(MY_CLASSPATH=lib/*:properties:.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your classpath would be made from:

- The lib folder and all its files (lib/*)
- The properties folder and all its files (properties)
- The current dir (.)

The ":" its the separator used in unix systems, ";" would be for windows systems

So if you run your java class from /user/mydir then all this would be available in your classpath:

java MyClass.class

- /user/mydir/lib/xalan.jar
- /user/mydir/lib/xerces.jar
- /user/mydir/lib/xyz.jar
- /user/mydir/properties/config.properties
- /user/mydir/MyClass.class